# Export nodes inside Panels by their UUIDs through Features

Tags: 7, panels, importing-exporting, features

In D7, I have a panel page that uses several nodes as content. When I export the panel into a feature on my Dev using UUIDs and UUID Features, and import the feature into my Test environment, Drupal creates new nodes with the UUIDs as expected, but the Panel isn't updated to reference these new UUIDs and their respective new NIDs. Instead the Panel keeps referring to Dev's NIDs.

I've looked high and low for a solution to no avail. The closest I have come to a solution was:
https://www.drupal.org/node/827466
But it has been years and no update. Does anyone have any ideas/solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this module https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/danylevskyi/2399993
It will work fine, if you don't have reference fields in your node.